# How do I find out what port another process is running on besides the web process on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have a webhook URL and a normal web server (running HapiJS).

I'd like to proxy certain requests in HapiJS to the webhook server that's running on a private port but I need to know what the $PORT is on the other non `web` process.

Is there a way to find this port number?

Comment: No, there is no way to find that port number.

Comment: What a bummer! Thank you for the response. :) You should make it an answer so I can resolve this and give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find that port number.
Heroku dynos run on different runtimes. So even if you did know it, you would also need to figure out the IP address of that server, which would change with every deployment and once every 24 hours.

This would also not be very scalable, as the strength of heroku is to allow you to boot more dynos easily. If you rely on knowing where the other dyno is, you're losing that easy scaling.

You don't necessarily need this to communicate between processes though. Using a redis queue, you could enqueue asynchronous jobs to be processed by your worker process. Both processes would communicate, and they wouldn't need to know where the other one is.